# Is there way to customize system alerts?

Tags: xcode, uialertview, alertview

I need to replace standard alert that asks permission to access user location with my own. Is it possible?

Or is there way to customize system alerts?

Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add the reason of the use of location, you are not able to change the alert yourself.

Add the following :

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to determine your location, to check where you are on a route.</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to determine your location, to check where you are on a route.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need to determine your location, to check where you are on a route.</string>
```

Before iOS 8 it uses `NSLocationUsageDescription`, iOS 8 it use `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` for the always use location and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` when using the location when you app is active.